# Скрыть текст в Inkscape

Tags: текст, inkscape

Есть 1000 svg картинок внутри которых содержится слои с изображением и текст, мне нужно экспортировать только изображения в *.png, как скрыть или удалить текст?,так как руками не вариант экпорт делаю через командную строку >inkscape D:\Test\1.svg -С -e D:\Test\1.png но в этом случае экпортируется все включая текст. На официальном сайте не нашел инфу какой командой выполнить скрытие / удаление текста в *.svg перед экспортом. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Подскажем, если не про авторские права речь)

Comment: @edem Спасибо! Это исключительно для внутреннего использования.

Answer (score 1):

Решение простое:
Удалит слой с текстом
ваш_svg --select=название_слоя_с_текстом --verb=EditDelete --verb=FileSave --verb=FileQuit